# Modeling Golf Ball rolling around in golf hole

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, models

I am trying to model a rotating/rolling golf ball’s interaction with a golf hole.

The boring case is just the ball rebounding in an elastic collision off the wall, with conservation of momentum determining how it spins after rebounding.

The fun case is the ball rolling along the edge of the cylindrical hole, something you get when you have a small angle of entry into the hole. How can I determine the path the ball takes after it enters the hole?

Generalizing, how do you model a sphere rolling along a wall determined by a path in the xy-plane? For example, a golf ball rolling around in a cardioid-shaped, rather than circular hole? I presume solving this for the 2d case allows us to just add gravity and have it take the same path, but moving downwards as well.

The original draft of this question included having homotopies of paths to generalize it further, but I realized that I’m making things more complicated than they need to be.

I haven’t found any good resources for this.

Comment: We need some initial conditions. Could start assuming no slipping initially, but that can be dealt with too. For rolling, it can have any velocity vector and rolls in that direction to start i guess. Wish j had time to play w this, but i dont. But here is: Modelling and simulation of a sphere rolling on the inside of a rough vertical cylinder https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/13873950500098747 ,

Comment: I believe rough means more than just no-slip. There is a coefficient of rolling friction mu that provides the min of (normal force times mu, the amount needed to have pure rolling) but energy is conserved, unlike w sliding friction. So *normally* v and omega are set and energy conserved and you have angular accel and translational decel. But here gravity and centripidal as a function of v. Energy still onserved if include Pot Energy of height. Rough is more than that if i recall, theres energy loss. Im sure they tell you. I enjoy audio more than most do. They want video or articles. Good luck!

Comment: Just to add to the aforementioned reference, here is a video of a ball rolling without slip inside a cylinder: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1t1grbgT5pE